# filterUsingPredicate in swift gives error "Void is not convertible to NSArray"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Hello I am not able to solve this error. please give me the relevant code for this

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "offerTitle LIKE[cd] %@", regionName);
 var arrRegion : [NSArray] = arrOffers.filterUsingPredicate(predicate);
```

Second line gives error : "`void convertible to NSArray`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filterUsingPredicate` *modifies* a (mutable) array and does not return a result.
What you probably want is

```
var arrRegion : NSArray = arrOffers.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

which does not modify the receiver, but *returns* the filtered array.

Comment: I want to check the array property (count).. How can i cast like as a mutable array... So i can check the count property

Comment: @SidShah: I do not understand, why cast to mutable array? `let count = arrRegion.count` gives you the count. If you need a mutable copy then `let mutableArray = arrRegion.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray` should do it.